# Is there a way to add a constant value dynamically to all records returned in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, apache-tez

I want to do the following query in Hive v1.2.1, where `field_3` is queried from another table.

```
select user_id, start_date, field_3 as stop_date
from some_table;
```

For every record returned, the value of `field_3` is the same. The problem is that it is stored in another table. To get that value, I can get it as follows.

```
select max(some_field) as stop_date
from another_table;
```

For now, I have hard-coded the literal.

```
select user_id, start_date, cast(cast('2017-10-19' as date) as timestamp) as stop_date
from some_table;
```

However, this approach is undesirable as the appropriate value will change throughout the day.

Any solution should consider if it will work plugged into Spark via the Hive SQL context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the output from another table..

```
select user_id, start_date, b.field_3 as stop_date FROM 
some_table a,
( select max(some_field) as field_3 
from another_table ) b;
```

Comment: I don't think that works. There's 3 `FROM`. If I remove the last `FROM` then it works as expected. Please revise and I'll accept.